# Get the selected TextView value in a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I am trying to get a `TextView` value out of the selected item within the `RecyclerView`. My `RecyclerView` layout file has two `TextView`s, one for the name and the other for the date as you can see here:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/layout_recyclerview_view_list_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/layout_recyclerview_view_list_date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/layout_recyclerview_view_list_name"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/layout_recyclerview_view_list_name"
    android:layout_below="@+id/layout_recyclerview_view_list_name" />
```

This is my adapter class for the `RecyclerView`:

```
List<ListsRecyclerViewList> list;

public ListsRecyclerViewListAdapter(List<ListsRecyclerViewList> list) {
    this.list = list;
}

@Override
public ListsRecyclerViewListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_recyclerview_view_list, parent, false);
    ListsRecyclerViewListViewHolder viewHolder = new ListsRecyclerViewListViewHolder(view);

    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ListsRecyclerViewListViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.name.setText(list.get(position).getName());
    holder.date.setText(list.get(position).getDate());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

public static class ListsRecyclerViewListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView name;
    TextView date;

    public ListsRecyclerViewListViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        this.name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.layout_recyclerview_view_list_name);
        this.date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.layout_recyclerview_view_list_date);
    }
}
```

This is the `onClick` event that launches the other activity as I mentioned earlier:

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
            new ListsRecyclerViewListListener(this,
                    new ListsRecyclerViewListListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ListsEditListActivity.class);
                            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

                            bundle.putString("name", /*this is where I need to set the value*/);
                            intent.putExtras(bundle);

                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    })
    );
```

This is the class that sets the values for the `List` and `RecyclerView`:

```
public String name;
public String date;

public ListsRecyclerViewList(String name, String date) {
    this.name = name;
    this.date = date;
}
```

How can I get the name field from the selected item within the `RecyclerView` and pass it to another activity? Any suggestions?

Comment: You should get your view on touch of your recycle view and initialize your both TextViews in that method using the reference of that view. From that you can get the value of that both TextViews

Comment: Piyush, could you please elaborate maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `viewHolder.name.getText(list.get(position).name)`. This will get the text from a `TextView` at the position stored in the variable `position`.